# Set Windows 10 Taskbar settings via Group Policy

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

Is it possible to enable/disable specific settings the Windows 10 Taskbar menu? Preferably via GPO. We are running Windows 10 Pro.

[image: windows10 taskbar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can utilize a built-in Group Policy to **Lock the Taskbar** by enabling the following:

```
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar . Lock the Taskbar
```

For the others, you may need to utilize registry updates.  To use small/large taskbar buttons, you can modify the following:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
>
> **TaskbarSmallIcons** DWORD
>
> 0 = Large taskbar buttons
> 1 = Small taskbar buttons

([Source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/25233-taskbar-buttons-use-large-small-size-windows-10-a.html))

To hide or show badges on taskbar buttons, modify the following:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
>
> **TaskbarBadges** DWORD
>
> 0 = Hide badges
> 1 = Show badges

([Source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48186-taskbar-buttons-hide-show-badges-windows-10-a.html))

To show the Command Prompt or PowerShell on the <kbd>[image: Winkey]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> menu, modify the following:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
>
> **DontUsePowerShellOnWinX** DWORD
>
> 0 = Show "Windows PowerShell"
> 1= Show "Command Prompt"

([Source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/22882-win-x-menu-show-command-prompt-powershell-windows-10-a.html))

That being said, if these machines are on a domain you can use [Group Policy Preferences](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn581922(v=ws.11).aspx) to implement those registry updates.

Answer (score 1):

For local GP, check `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar`

Comment: Apparently you need Enterprise or Education version of Windows to customize the Task Bar via GPO: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/customize-windows-10-start-screens-by-using-group-policy